# How to append a tag with specific id using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

i want to append a  tag to  with different ids, for eg.

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
```

if i use `$('div').append('<span>Hello World</span>);`
then it attached the `<span>` tag with every `<div>`, but i want to attach it to only 1 div based on it id. for example some time to 4 some times to 3 etc.

Comment: How is the script/function meant to know to which element the new content should be appended?

Comment: i dont know, how to accomplish this thing. I am also asking how to do this thing

Comment: can you not select using the id??  like this: `$('#3').append`

Comment: ``$("div[id=1]'").append('<span>Hello World</span>')``

Answer (score 5):

Use the wonderful id selector offered by JQuery:)

```
$("#1").append('<span>Hello World</span>');
```

Comment: numbers cannot be used as ids

Comment: You forgot the closing quote at the end of your string

Comment: @Kishore HTML5 specification supports numbers as IDs.

Comment: @radashk unless he is using HTML5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @VisioN IE6 has no transparency by default, but who cares :)

Comment: @GTSouza IE6 is a browser? :)

Comment: @VisioN nice one :P, but is a bad idea use numbers with ID, if the project is a big thing you will be lost to manage the DOM

Answer (score 3):

Just use the ID selector:

```
$('#1').append('<span>Hello World</span>');
```

**Edit: *IF you don't use HTML5:***

You can't use numbers in IDs or classes when they don't follow a char. So you need use id="div1" instead:

```
$('#div1').append('<span>Hello World</span>');
```

Comment: HTML5 specification supports numbers as IDs.

Comment: Numbers only? I read the post from Kishore in the other comment and there it says the same: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters

Comment: The working draft for HTML 5 is even more permissive, saying only that an id must contain at least one character and may not contain any space characters. (character == digit or letter?)

Comment: @ShogunArts.de Yep, you can use even special characters.

Comment: Was something new to me with the numbers only :)

Comment: Edited my answer in case someone is reading it and don't use html5